# Service becomes unresponsive with many sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, servicehost

I have a WCF service with a NetTcpBinding running with about 100 clients. The clients regulary poll information from the server and after a while the service does not respond anymore.

Looking at netstat, I can see many connections that are in the CLOSE_WAIT state.

This is my binding:

```
<netTcpBinding>
  <binding  name="default" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10000">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

I have also tried to change the values of **closeTimeout** from the default of 00:01:00 to **00:00:10**, but with no effect.

The machine is a Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.

**Update:**

I have added a `ServiceThrottlingBehavior` now, but the result is still the same.

```
new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
{
 MaxConcurrentCalls = 1000,
 MaxConcurrentInstances = 1000,
 MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000
};
```

**Update2**

I have set the SessionMode to NotAllowed and changed the binding to streamed.

Any ideas what I could do to improve performance or to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it seems: 1. initially the clients were able to connect to your server with no problem, so this rules out configuration problem 2. After a while server stopped responding, but you didn't say how long, and how big is the request rate, and whether the server stopped responding at all, or only intermittently responding. Based on this one possibility is that something is wrong on the server side. Did you noticed anything unusual on the server side? Things to look for is:

1. Thread count -- was the thread pool being depicted (as some settings
   may set a cap on thread pool thread)? Especially try a fresh launch
   of the server and observe the thread count till it stopped
   responding, any pattern there? You may have dead locks, long
   blocking operations etc. which holds thread for too long.
2. Memory -- is there a problem with memory leaks?
3. Is it a self hosting service? Do you have proper code to catch ServiceHost.Faulted event (and
   restart the service)? If a ServiceHost is faulted, it'll not respond
   to any requests.
4. See what [WCF performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) tells you, especially the queue size and number of active connections. From the performance counter, you'll know whether the service is taking any request, or if your throttling
   configurations are necessary at all.
5. The ultimate diagnostic tool: turned on service side [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx)? Open a trace file will
   definitely tell you what happened with a request. If you see any
   exception in the tracing file, you'll find your root cause.

Comment: It turned out to be a combination of several problems. There were some operations that took very long to complete, in the meantime the client would time out. But since the operation was still running, the server only closed the socker after the operation was completed and it realized that the client has already disconnected. Your answer is a good summary of the steps you can take in this situation, mostly without making any code modifications.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your clients are never disconnecting.

1. Are you sure your clients are correctly closing the channel? Note that you should call ChannelFactory.Close, not just Dispose.
2. Set the receiveTimeout to something low to verify this is the problem.

Comment: Accourding to the documentation: CLOSE_WAIT indicates that the server has received the first FIN signal from the client and the connection is in the process of being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your client closed the connection by calling close(), which sent FIN to the server socket, which ACKed the FIN and the state of which now changed to CLOSE_WAIT, and stays that way unless the server issues close() call on that socket.

Your server program needs to detect whether the client has aborted the connection, and then close() it immediately to free up the port. How? Refer to read(). Upon reading end-of-file (meaning FIN is received), zero is returned.

You can detect if client is disconnected.

Any WCF channel implements **ICommunicationObject** , which provides events for the channel lifetime.

You should listen to the Faulted event
The sessionId can be accessed as always from the OperationContext.Current property.
When your client open the channel (on the first operation), register to the adequate events:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);
```

and

```
void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Logout((IContextChannel)sender);
 }

 protected void Logout(IContextChannel channel)
 {
        string sessionId = null;

        if (channel != null)
        {
            sessionId = channel.SessionId;
        }
 }
```

if the socket is disconnected, you should get a channel Fault event. The Closed event is raised when the client shuts down gracefully, the Faulted when it's unexpected (as in case of network failure).

check out following link.. Its kind a similar . It helped me ..

[TCP Socket Server Builds Up CLOSE_WAITs Occasionally Over Time Until Inoperable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679643/tcp-socket-server-builds-up-close-waits-occasionally-over-time-until-inoperable)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the router isn't the problem, since some consumer grade routers have a cap on the number of allowed open sockets/connections.